# MVC-4 Assigning Employees and Manager to Department Scenerio and EF-CodeFirst

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a Department Table with Fields

```
public class Department
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]        
    [StringLength(100)]

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location UsersCompanyLocation { get; set; }
}
```

and an Employee Table

```
public class Employee
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]        
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string IDCardNo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]        
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }


    public int? DesignationId { get; set; }
    public Designations EmployeeDesignation { get; set; }


    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department UserDepartment { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company", ResourceType = typeof(Translations.Translation))]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Company UserCompany { get; set; }


    public int? LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location UsersCompanyLocation { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Pic", ResourceType = typeof(Translations.Translation))]
    public string Pic { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "HireDate", ResourceType = typeof(Translations.Translation))]
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "DateofBirth", ResourceType = typeof(Translations.Translation))]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "MaritalStatus", ResourceType = typeof(Translations.Translation))]
    public string MaritialStatus { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]        
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(256)]        
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string PersonalEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(256)]        
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string OfficialEmail { get; set; }


    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Roles UserRole { get; set; }

    public int? EmploymentStatusID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employment EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Now my Scenerio is thatI want To Assign one Employee as Manager to a Department and from the remaining pool of Employees, i may assign Employees to That Department. I am using code first EF technique, I am not able to make a proper class to work with this scenerio. Secondly I want to use List Box twice, first from which we may select just 1 employee as Manager and Second from which I want to select multiple employees from the remaing pool of Employees. Can any one help me in this scenerio

I have done the database portion after using up the whole day

I have to make another table (offcourse a class in EF CodeFirst) "DepartmentManager"

```
public class DepartmentManager
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department AssignedDepartment { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee ManagerialEmployee { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DepartmentEmployees> DepartmentEmployees { get; set; }
```

This table has A UserID foreign key, Now for assignig employees to the Department, i will make another table "DepartmentEmployees" with composite keys

```
public class DepartmentEmployees
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }        
}
```

Now two things to ask, how to make foreign key `UserID`  unique so that it may not be repeated, 2nd how to use `List Box` such that in one `List Box` just one Employee is Selected and in 2nd one, we may select the remainging employees, and how to fill the 2nd `List Box` such that an employee which has been selected as Manager doesn't appear in the 2nd `List Box` ??????????????

Comment: I think that this model doesn't work for you. Because your properties for relationship aren't right form.